# Creating Interface between Game and Android Game

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to implement the Facebook SDK in the android game i am creating.

I have created a master game where all of my logic happens and the I have created an Android version which uses the master. Hope this makes sense.

Anyway in order to fire a button press in my master code with code in the android version i am trying to use an Interface to accomplish this but i keep getting the following error;

FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 56457
java.lang.NullPointerException

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any help. I have put my code below.

FacebookInterface.java (master)

```
package com.gksoftworks.ECHelpers;

public interface FacebookInterface {

    public void FacebookShare();

}
```

InputHandler.java (master)

```
package com.gksoftworks.ECHelpers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.gksoftworks.GameWorld.GameWorld;
import com.gksoftworks.ui.*;
import com.gksoftworks.GameObjects.Chick;

public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {
private Chick myChick;
private GameWorld myWorld;

private List<SimpleButton> menuButtons;

private List<SimpleButton> gameOverButtons;

// List of all buttons
private SimpleButton easyButton;
private SimpleButton mediumButton;
private SimpleButton hardButton;
private SimpleButton randomButton;
private SimpleButton rateButton;
private SimpleButton shareButton;
private SimpleButton difficultyButton;
private SimpleButton retryButton;

private float scaleFactorX;
private float scaleFactorY;

private FacebookInterface fbInterface;

public InputHandler(GameWorld myWorld, float scaleFactorX,
        float scaleFactorY) {
    this.myWorld = myWorld;
    myChick = myWorld.getChick();

    int midPointY = myWorld.getMidPointY();

    this.scaleFactorX = scaleFactorX;
    this.scaleFactorY = scaleFactorY;

    menuButtons = new ArrayList<SimpleButton>();

    gameOverButtons = new ArrayList<SimpleButton>();

    // Add the easy button
    easyButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.easyButton.getRegionWidth() / 2),
            midPointY + -11, 24, 16, AssetLoader.easyButton,
            AssetLoader.easyButton);
    menuButtons.add(easyButton);

    // Add the medium button
    mediumButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.mediumButton.getRegionWidth() / 2),
            midPointY + 9, 35, 16, AssetLoader.mediumButton,
            AssetLoader.mediumButton);
    menuButtons.add(mediumButton);

    // Add the hard button
    hardButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.hardButton.getRegionWidth() / 2),
            midPointY + 29, 25, 16, AssetLoader.hardButton,
            AssetLoader.hardButton);
    menuButtons.add(hardButton);

    // Add the random button
    randomButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.randomButton.getRegionWidth() / 2),
            midPointY + 48, 37, 16, AssetLoader.randomButton,
            AssetLoader.randomButton);
    menuButtons.add(randomButton);

    // Add the rate button
    rateButton = new SimpleButton(5, 2, 60, 16, AssetLoader.rateButton, AssetLoader.rateButton);
    menuButtons.add(rateButton);

    // Add the share button
    shareButton = new SimpleButton(70, 2, 60, 16, AssetLoader.shareButton, AssetLoader.shareButton);
    menuButtons.add(shareButton);

    // Add the rate button
    difficultyButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.difficultyButton.getRegionWidth() / 2),
            midPointY + 16, 65, 16, AssetLoader.difficultyButton,
            AssetLoader.difficultyButton);
    gameOverButtons.add(difficultyButton);

    // Add the rate button
    retryButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.retry.getRegionWidth() / 2),
            midPointY + 38, 33, 16, AssetLoader.retry,
            AssetLoader.retry);
    gameOverButtons.add(retryButton);

}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    screenX = scaleX(screenX);
    screenY = scaleY(screenY);

    if (myWorld.isMenu()) {
        easyButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
        mediumButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
        hardButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
        randomButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
        rateButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
        shareButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
    } else if (myWorld.isReady()) {
        myWorld.start();
        myChick.onClick();
    } else if (myWorld.isRunning()) {
        myChick.onClick();
    }

    if (myWorld.isGameOver() || myWorld.isHighScore()) {
        difficultyButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
        retryButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    screenX = scaleX(screenX);
    screenY = scaleY(screenY);

    if (myWorld.isMenu()) { 
        if (easyButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            myWorld.ready(1);
            return true;
        } else if (mediumButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            myWorld.ready(2);
            return true;
        } else if (hardButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            myWorld.ready(3);
            return true;
        } else if (randomButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            myWorld.ready(4);
            return true;
        } else if (rateButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            Gdx.net.openURI("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gksoftworks.EasterChick");
        } else if (shareButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            fbInterface.FacebookShare();
        }
    } else if (myWorld.isGameOver()) {
        if (difficultyButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            myWorld.restart(true);
        } else if (retryButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
            myWorld.restart(false);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}

private int scaleX(int screenX) {
    return (int) (screenX / scaleFactorX);
}

private int scaleY(int screenY) {
    return (int) (screenY / scaleFactorY);
}

public List<SimpleButton> getMenuButtons() {
    return menuButtons;
}

public List<SimpleButton> getGameOverButtons() {
    return gameOverButtons;
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


}
```

So I create my Facebook interface here and use it when the share button is pressed.

MainActivity.java (Android)

```
package com.gksoftworks.EasterChick;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.gksoftworks.ECHelpers.FacebookInterface;
//import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.gksoftworks.EasterChick.ECGame;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements FacebookInterface {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new ECGame(), false);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-0674036768511172/5754826717");


    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("CB5125BK84")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequestBanner);

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);

}

@Override
public void FacebookShare(){
     Gdx.app.log("AndroidGame","Hello Android");
} 


}
```

So i implement it as part of this activity and i get the error. When I press the button should it not display in logcat the code i have done in Android?

Can anyone help?

Comment: if you want us to help you, please post stack trace

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 56457
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.gksoftworks.ECHelpers.InputHandler.touchUp(InputHandler.java:151)

at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:360)

at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:498)

at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)

Comment: not sure is it complete code, but in snippet which you provided, you are not instantiate any of your fields, so this might be one of reasons, if you are instantiate them, could you tell us which line is 151 in your input handler

Comment: Sorry, didn;t add complete code. I have edited the post above to show the whole input handler. Line 151 is;

fbInterface.FacebookShare();

Comment: can you show us how you instantiate `fbInterface` ? as you have error in this line `fbInterface.FacebookShare()` only thing which can be null is fbInterface`

Comment: Ok I just do this at the top of the class;

`private FacebookInterface fbInterface;`

Comment: this is just definition, your `fbInterface` is not initialize there

Comment: where do I initialise it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FacebookInterface fbInterface` is definition not initialization, to initialize class you have to create instance of it. as you have interface, you might need to create class which implements `FacebookInterface` interface

you can use anonymous class

```
FacebookInterface fbInterface = new FacebookInterface(){
    @Override
    public void FacebookShare(){
        Gdx.app.log("AndroidGame","Hello Android");
   } 
}
```

that should fix your `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thanks, that does fix the `NullPointerException` but then how do i use the interface in my android app?

If i try;

`public void FacebookShare() {
   Gdx.app.log("AndroidGame","Hello Android");
}`

from the android app it does not show me Hello Android

Comment: that should be displayed somewhere in your logcat, unless you have logging switched off, try to replace this with android `Log.i`

Comment: It does display in LogCat regardless of which application I run i.e. I also get it if I run the desktop version.

I have 2 apps that both inherit the master app you see.

Do I just put your code into the MainActivity for the android app? The InputHandler is in the master app.

Comment: as it is using android log, i think it will be better if you keep it with android, but i dont think all what it will be doing is logging, so i think it will be best if you pass `FacebookInterface` to your handler via constructor

Comment: Ahhh Excellent. Your suggestion worked a treat. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How I always do it is somewhat like you, create an interface, some function to call in MainActivity through it and initialize it in the main game class in the core project.

Game.java

```
    public static FacebookInterface myRequestHandler;

    public Game(FacebookInterface handler) {
         myRequestHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
         setScreen(new Splash());
    }

    @Override
         public void dispose() {
         super.dispose();
    }

    etc...
```

Then i just call it in any class  (don't forget to import the Game class) for example, by using

```
    Game.myRequestHandler.FacebookShare();
```

Give that a go and hopefully it will work.

Comment: @user3489088 - Edited the answer for a different approach.

Comment: Ok, doing it that way I still get the NullPointerException come up in LogCat

Answer (score 0):

There may well be larger issues, but it looks like the variables in `InputHandler` have not been initialized, therefore `myWorld` is null (as well as the buttons).

Comment: Interesting, the rest of the buttons do work i.e. the rateButton that brings up the google play store works without a problem which is why i thought it has been initialised by this point.